# Python check file for asynchronous changes

Tags: python, performance

I want to read a file and inspect its changes live .When i  use infinitive while loop , it creates a heavy cpu usage.The file i'm trying to read is also getting inputs from  an another program .What is the correct way to approach this kind of problems ?

Comment: just use a sleep(0.1) and the cpu load will be gone.

Answer (score 1):

Please look at [pyinotify](http://pyinotify.sourceforge.net/) module for Python if you're on Linux. It's a port for inotify - Linux Kernel feature.